# User permission to create new File Descriptor

Tags: linux, centos, bash, centos8, file-descriptors

On **CentOS 8** I have a **Bash** script which uses a non-standard **file descriptor** (`/dev/fd/5`) and needs to be executed by a standard user (not `root`).

When the user executes the script it receives

```
tee: /dev/fd/5: Permission denied
```

The code snippet which is raising this error is this:

```
# Print message both to stdout and FD5
msg() {
    msg="$1"
    echo "$msg" | tee /dev/fd/5
}
```

What kind of permission I should give to user to let it create and use a new File Descriptor?

Answer (score 2):

There's no permission you can give for a program to write to a read only section of the `/proc` filesystem.

Take a look at the path you used `/dev/fd/5`. Notice that `/dev/fd` is actually a symlink to `/proc/self/fd`. This means that these descriptors reference each program's own open files.

When you ask `tee` to write to `/dev/fd/5` it can't do so because `/proc/self/fd/5` doesn't exist. It doesn't exist because `tee` didn't open it. And the kernel won't allow it to be created as a regular file.

If the file descriptor was opened by the script, then you should just send output there directly.

```
echo "$msg" >&5
```

If the file descriptor was *not* opened by the script, you need to rethink your approach to whatever you are doing.

Comment: Ok, so why this is working with root user?

Comment: @Mat Who knows? Maybe it's put random files named `5` somewhere. Since your example is contrived, it's very difficult to guess.